# How to use force_ssl with a 302

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I put this in config/environments/production.rb , my site will become all SSL using 301 redirects (permanent).

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

How do I do this using 302 redirects (temporary)?

[RubyOnRails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html) says to use :status, but I'm still not sure how I would do this in the production.rb file.  (This is Rails 3.2.13 on Heroku.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this into your main controller

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl_redirect({:status => :found})

def new
    # Non-SSL access will be redirected to SSL
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, here's another question then... what would be the difference between 'config.force_ssl = true' in production.rb and 'force_ssl' in application_controller.rb? I mean, how does rails process each request differently?

Comment: If you add it in configuration it will enable the option globally but including it in controller will only enable it for that controller action. It gives you better control on which action should it work and on which it should not.

Comment: What does :found do? Is the documentation online for this somewhere?  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Found send status 302, which you wanted. Checkout this link http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/7/4/rails-http-status-code-to-symbol-mapping and if it really helped you please vote up the answers.